# Cuda error out of memory

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I bought Alienware Gpu 1070 for deep learning. 
but somehow simple Tensorflow running is slower than when I was running Tensorflow on my old only CPU old Dell computer. 
and I got

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:126] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:136] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:806] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 123.25M (129236992 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
```

for simple Tensorflow running.

my nvidia-smi setting as follow

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.81                 Driver Version: 384.81                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   49C    P0    31W /  N/A |   7915MiB /  8105MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1053      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           299MiB |
|    0      1985      G   compiz                                       257MiB |
|    0     26444      G   ...-token=35E56369B532703BC65298BE4DF4A2E8   121MiB |
|    0     27364      C   /home/jake/tensorflow/bin/python3           6997MiB |
|    0     29540      C   /home/jake/tensorflow/bin/python3            235MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I can not guess why my new GPU computer makes so much sound and so much slower than my old computer.

is there other settings I should do for  Deep learning with GPU?

Comment: So did it run, only slower, or did it not run at all (OOM error)? You posted an error but asked about why your GPU runs slower.

Comment: Do `watch -n 1 nvidia-smi` and see the GPU utilization getting updated every one second.